# Does GORM support working with encrypted SQLite DB?

Tags: sqlite, go, orm, go-gorm

I have a requirement for using an ORM for my Go application which can connect to a postgreSQL db or SQLite db.

The docs of gorm don't mention anything about connecting to an encrypted sqlite db.

Is it possible to use it or any way of providing a custom driver for sqlite which will work with and encrypted SQlite DB?

**UPDATE**

As per Ezequiel Muns comment, I updated the gorm SQLite driver code to use [github.com/mutecomm/go-sqlcipher](https://github.com/mutecomm/go-sqlcipher).

This new GORM driver can be found [here](https://github.com/jackfr0st13/gorm-sqlite-cipher).

Cheers !!

Comment: I can't imagine why it wouldn't work. What happens when you try? GORM is just a wrapper around the standard access libraries.

Comment: https://github.com/CovenantSQL/go-sqlite3-encrypt and https://github.com/mutecomm/go-sqlcipher are the two packages I see for connecting to an encrypted db and both use the sql package of Go. I wasn't able to make these work with GORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorm uses a system of drivers that adapt the individual database clients for its use.

You'd have to create a new module that copies the source of [`go-gorm/driver/sqlite`](https://github.com/go-gorm/sqlite) but updating https://github.com/go-gorm/sqlite/blob/master/sqlite.go#L8 to import the alternate library of your choice. Since these are forks and they comply with the database/sql interface, it should just work. You'll then be able to use this new driver as per normal in gorm:

```golang
import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    sqliteEncrypt "path.to/your/gorm-sqlite-encrypt"
)

db, err := gorm.Open(sqliteEncrypt.Open("file:dbFileName?_crypto_key=auxten"), gorm.Options{})
if err != nil {
    panic("failed to connect database")
}
// ...
```

Note: You could try to to avoid having to update any source in `go-gorm/driver/sqlite` by making use of the [go.mod replace directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace), though I don't know how that plays with CGO modules that don't themselves have a `go.mod` file as is the case with the two libraries you linked.

Comment: This worked great !! Thank you so much. I have edited the question as per your suggestion to include the driver I created which is now published and can be used by others seeking the same.